# Double quotes in Rscript.exe expressions using Powershell

Tags: r

I can't seem to correctly pass double quotes to R when sending expressions to
Rscript.exe using the "-e" flag in Powershell.

When I try the command for standard Windows command line from
the ?Rscript documentation:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe' -e "date()" -e "format(Sys.time(), \"%a %b %d %X %Y\")"
```

It returns:

```
[1] "Thu Jan 31 20:27:53 2019"
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
```

From how I understand Powershell strings, I expected this to work:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe' -e 'date()' -e 'format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y")'
```

But it returns:

```
[1] "Thu Jan 31 20:36:02 2019"
Error: unexpected input in "format(Sys.time(), %a"
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know how I should be formatting these commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quote for both R *and* Powershell. Use \" for the first, and doubled "" for the second.

```
'format(Sys.time(), \""%a %b %d %X %Y\"")'
```

Comment: Running `& 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\bin\Rscript.exe' -e "date()" -e 'format(Sys.time(), \""%a %b %d %X %Y\"")'` gives `[1] "Thu Jan 31 21:23:07 2019"
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "format(Sys.time(), %a %"
Execution halted`